# Gradle: exclude build.gradle.kts in a subdirectory

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to tell Gradle

"Hey, there's a build.gradle.kts in the directory some/subdir, but please act like it's not there and don't try to mess with it at all"?

I have to keep a non-Android Kotlin project in an Android repository with a build.gradle.kts-file in the repository root for ... reasons ... and it keeps breaking my build due to plugin version conflicts.

The hierarchy layout is as follows:

```
|-- build.gradle.kts
|-- settings.gradle.kts
|-- src/
    |-- android_project_a/
        |-- build.gradle.kts
    |-- android_project_b/
        |-- build.gradle.kts
|-- kotlin_project/
    |-- build.gradle.kts // This is what I need to exclude
```

Comment: there are more than one way, But if you can share the root `build.gradle`, `setting.gradle` and directory hierarchy, It can be helpful to suggest a solution, please update the question when you can.

Comment: Actually, I needed the `build.gradle` and `setting.gradle` as well, but I will post an answer in a second.

Comment: Those two are on top of the list, or not?

`build.gradle.kts` and `settings.gradle.kts` are just the Kotlin versions of `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`, aren't they?

Comment: Am not used to kotlin, but with groovy build and setting root, contain the sub projects that need to be build and assembled once you trigger a root project command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using command line to build, You can execute subdir as following

```
gradle build -x kotlin_project:build
```

But this is not a nice way to have it done, I wanted to check your `build.gradle` and `setting.gradle`, As you can change that once and for all, If you change the sub-projects and implementation of your sub-projects.

This `kotlin_project` should be a part of your `setting.gradle` as its being build automatically when you trigger root dir build.

You can exclude it if you want, But you have to remove it as well from dependencies at your `build.gradle`

Comment: You're right. I've inspected my `settings.gradle.kts` and what it does is to just include every subproject it finds, which explains the behaviour I have. I'll add some logic to it to exclude the project I don't want.